# How to add template parameter to this code for Whatsapp Cloud Api?

Tags: php, api, curl, cloud, whatsapp

I use this code to send static message template but i kan not figer out how to change it to send template parameter in it.

```
    $number = "myphone";
    $template = array(
       'name'=>'new_booking',
       'language'=>array('code'=>'sv')
    );

     $params = array(
     'messaging_product'=>'whatsapp', 
     'to'=>$number, 'type'=>'template', 
     'from'=>'4620899232', 
     'access_token'=>'XXX',
     'template'=>json_encode($template)
     );

        $endpoint = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/109328925422504/messages';
     
        $headers = array('Authorization'=>'XXX','Content-Type'=>'application/json');
        $url = $endpoint . '?' . http_build_query($params);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        $result = curl_exec($ch );
        echo $result; //you can skip this, I did it to check the results
        curl_close( $ch );
```

I tried to edit code by myself bud no result :-(

Update.
So the problem is that this code works fine as is with statisc message template that has no {{1}} = template parameter.
I woild like to ad one parameter (some text) to the code so it inserts the poarametr to the the template and sends it.

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying to ask here. You are already inserting this dynamically into your parameter array, with `'template'=>json_encode($template)`. So what about this is not working? You need to give us an actual _problem description_, instead of just "unable to figure out".